# Give a proof of IVT using uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I was asked to:

> Give a proof of IVT using uniform continuity.

Assume that $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$. Let $f(a)<\gamma < f(b)$.

Since $[a,b]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous. Thus given $\epsilon>0$, if we divide $[a,b]$ into sufficiently large number of small subintervals of the same length, for at least one division point $x$ we must have $|f(x)-\gamma|<\epsilon$. Let $(\epsilon_n, p_n)$ be a sequence where $\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $p_n$ is a corresponding to that epsilon point such that $|f(p_n)-\gamma|<\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Since $p_1,p_2,\ldots $ is a sequence of points in a compact subspace $[a,b]$, it must contain a convergent subsequence, denote its limit by $p$. I have troubles in showing that $f(p)=\gamma$. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f(p)-\gamma|\leq |f(p)-f(p_n)|+|f(p_n)-\gamma|$ by the triangle inequality.

You can make the first term arbitrarily small by continuity and the second small by the definition of $p_n$.